# How use twitter digits api multiple times for same number?

Tags: android, backend, twitter-digits

I am developing mobile app, where user have to login by using Twitter Digits Api and my backend. So, the problem is, that I can't test it multiple times, because when I register my phone number, I can't use the same number for next time during debugging/development. So, does twitter digits have some test methods, so I can use the same number many times?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `Digits.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();`? It should clear your session and let you login again.